# matplotlib contour plot in given range

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I need to draw ellipses like in the picture given below. Code is taken from one tutorial. But I need to draw ellipses in range X:[-10,-10] and Y: [-2, -2]. How should I modify my code?

```
fig = plt.figure()
x = linspace(0, 10, 51)
y = linspace(0, 8, 41)
(X, Y) = meshgrid(x, y)
a = exp(-((X - 2.5) ** 2 + (Y - 4) ** 2) / 4)
c = plt.contour(x, y, a)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
```

will restrict the drawing to that region.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
a = np.exp(-((X - 0) ** 2 + 3*(Y - 0) ** 2) / 4)
c = plt.contour(x, y, a)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

```
1*(X - A) ** 2 + 3*(Y - B) ** 2) == 0
```

Is the equation for an ellipse with center at (A, B). 
Play around with the constants (e.g. 1 and 3) to see how it stretches the ellipse in the X- and Y-directions.

Comment: but then the plot is not visible. How should I modify the function so that it would be visible?